# DataTable - Disabled pagination

Tags: jquery, datatables

I need to do the following:

```
$("#example").on( 'page.dt', function () 
{
    if ($("#txtField6").length){    
        alert("You must finish operation new/edit. The pagination is not posible");
        //when i press the buttons navigation, if this condition is met, I must stay on the same page, what can i do it?
    }
});
```

Comment: I assume you want inline editing. There are many other ways user can affect the table: sorting, filtering, changing page length. Instead of preventing all of this and not just pagination, maybe it's better to use modal dialog instead, as in [this example](https://editor.datatables.net/examples/simple/simple.html)? What is `#txtField6`, is this a field outside the table?

Answer (score 1):

The solution:

```
tbLoc.page(page.info());
```

Comment: This solution, not perfect functionality, sorry, i create other topic

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.