# DataTable - Disabled pagination v2

Tags: jquery, datatable

I need to do the following:

```
    var tbLoc = $("#example").DataTable();
    $("#example").on( 'page.dt', function () 
    {
        if ($("#txtField7").length){ //is add or edit row
            alert("You must finish operation new/edit. The pagination is not posible");     
            //when i press the buttons navigation, if this condition is met, I must stay on the same page, what can i do it?
            tbLoc.page(page.info()); //it works ok, but when cancel editing, pagination not work
        }
    });
```

With tbLoc.page(page.info()); i stay on the same page, is i want i, but it not works perfect, Also, when the instruction is executed (tbLoc.page (page.info ());), the pagination buttons not work correctly.

What is the problem?

Thanks,

Comment: possible duplicate of [DataTable - Disabled pagination](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31915821/datatable-disabled-pagination)

Comment: Please avoid posting duplicate questions. Update the original question instead with more details.

Answer (score 0):

You have default options in datatable if you want to disable paging

```
 var tbLoc = $("#example").DataTable({
   paging: false // this will disable pagination
  });
```